# Video format and MIME type error after deploying on tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to play .mp4 file on all browsers, I am using Spring-boot, html5 and thymeleaf. When I deploy the project on local machine, the video is working just fine but as I try to deploy the .jar file on tomact server in linux, I get the following exception.

[image]

I have cross checked the path of my video it is getting downloaded but when I try to open it, I get a message "the playback of this movie requires a mpeg-4 aac decoder plugin which is not installed". My code is given bellow:

```
 <video id="jatan-video" class="video-function" width="100%" controls>
      <source th:src="@{/images/videos/tom.mp4}" type="video/mp4"/>
 </video>
```

Comment: this might be helpful to you https://askubuntu.com/questions/214421/how-to-install-the-mpeg-4-aac-decoder-and-the-h-264-decoder

Answer (score 0):

Add this line `video/mp4 mp4 mp4v mpg4` in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\mime.types` if not present. Also, you may need to download some media player on the server.